# SQL Server - Concatenate previous 5 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, coalesce

I've got sql code which creates an average of the previous 5 rows within column1 after partitioning and ordering:

```
CAST (AVG(col1) OVER (Partition by col2 ORDER BY col3 ASC ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS DECIMAL(3,2)) AS col1avg
```

I want to do a similar thing, but instead of averaging the 5 values, I want to create a string with the 5 values separated by a comma.
I've tried multiple ideas with no success.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Your code is not compatible with SQL Server 2008.  Please tag the question with the right version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method in SQL Server 2012+ is to use `CONCAT()` and `LAG()`:

```
select CONCAT(LAG(col1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ',',
              LAG(col1, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ',',
              LAG(col1, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ',',
              LAG(col1, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ','
              LAG(col1, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3)
             )
```

If you need to handle `NULL` values, this is a bit trickier.  I would recommend using spaces, trim, and replace:

```
select REPLACE(RTRIM(CONCAT(LAG(col1, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ' ',
                            LAG(col1, 2, '') OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ' ',
                            LAG(col1, 3, '') OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ' ',
                            LAG(col1, 4, '') OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3), ' ',
                            LAG(col1, 5, '') OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3)
                           )
                    ), ' ', ','
              )
```

Comment: Thank you.  First solution works great (once I added an extra comma after each ',' ).  Feel free to update and I'll mark as complete.